# sensor implementation on different device manufacturer

Tags: java, sensors, android-sensors

Samsung  phone runs Android  operating System and  HTC  phone runs Android operating system (Assuming both Samsung and HTC phone have accelerometer sensor).

Can I use same Java code, which have been written for accessing data from accelerometer sensor on Samsung phone, for accessing data from accelerometer on Motorola phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can (and you should) use the same API, the [hardware Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/package-summary.html).